# Catch LDAP connection failure in F3

Tags: php, ldap, fat-free-framework

I'm using Auth class in Fat-Free Framework (F3) to authenticate users from OpenLDAP. However, the application couldn't capture errors such as `LDAP connection failure` generated by the Auth class constructor.

Is there a way to capture such errors and hide the detailed stack trace from the users?

Reference:
https://fatfreeframework.com/3.6/auth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class throws an error, rather than an exception, therefore it is not catchable.

However you can skip the error using the silent @ operator and check the result type (which should be a boolean):

```
 $res=@$auth->login('login','pass');
 if ($res===TRUE) {
   // login successful
 } elseif ($res===FALSE) {
   // wrong credentials
 } else {
   // LDAP connection failure
 }
```

If your concern is just to hide the debug stack trace from the users, then just set [DEBUG](https://fatfreeframework.com/3.6/quick-reference#DEBUG) to 0.